# Flask-Wtf Regex and Length Validation don't working

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

```py
class checkUserName(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',[Length(min=5, max=20),Regexp('[0-9A-Za-z_]+'),DataRequired('Required')])
```

I want to accept username only combination between number, character, and underscore like `admin` and reject username like `'''''''''''` with minimum length 5 and maximum length 20, but the validation didn't work, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code like this:

```
username = StringField('Username', validators=[Length(min=5, max=20),Regexp('[0-9A-Za-z_]+'),DataRequired('Required')])
```

or like this :

```
username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=5, max=20), validators.Regexp('[0-9A-Za-z_]+'), validators.DataRequired('Required')])
```

if you want `'''''''''''` accept as username you can change the regex like this:

```
("[0-9A-Za-z_']+")
```

that's mean you accept a set of character in square bracket and `+` mean the character ahead repeat by one or more time.

if you want to accept only `admin, admin''''` you can try this:

```
`("[0-9A-Za-z_]+'*")`
```

1. `[0-9A-Za-z_]+`  : accept a set of character in square bracket with one ore more repetition
2. `'*` : accept `'` character after the character above with 0 or more repetition.

Comment: The error exists in the third. admin''' should not accept. Accepts the third string.

Comment: so you meant to accept input admin'''', try the edited version.

Comment: I want it to not accept this string(admin''). But the words from A to z begin, and then the characters I don't want come and accept. This is the problem. sorry for my english

Comment: Try to add `validators` keyword to your code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this following error:

```
NameError: name 'Regexp' is not defined
```

And this is how I solved it:

```
from wtforms.validators import Regexp
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
from wtforms.validators import Length
```